# mount moto g on debian

Tags: linux, debian, mtp

Apparently Motorola's phones have MTP disabled (?) and can't find a way to transfer the files to my computer. Have read a bunch of links and none of them work. Have created the file `/etc/udev/51-android.rules` (sources [1](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#setting-up) and [2](https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules)) and `/etc/udev/69-libmtp.rules` ([source](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.tausys.de%2F2014%2F01%2F31%2Flinux-mint-16-und-moto-g-mtp%2F)) as the links show and nothing works.

The 51 file as I have it written

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", ATTR{idProduct}="2e76". MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

the 69 file as I have it written

```
# Motorola Moto G (MTP+?)
ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", ATTR{idProduct}=="2e76", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k",   MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

Since I am not really sure of what any of it means I have tried changing the ID of the vendor to `03f0` (hp, my computer) (know it makes no sense but I had to try since nothing was working), and the ID of the product to `2e82` a supposedly earlier version of my phone.

Other sources I have read that havent worked [link](https://codeyarns.com/2013/12/23/how-to-mount-moto-g-on-ubuntu-using-mtp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the MTP function is not available you can transfer your file through FTP.

The easy way :

- install the [**Wifi File Transfer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.minimax.wifishare.wififiletransfer) application on your android
  device
- Start the application , it will give you the `username` , the `password` and the url e,g `192.169.1.150:3332` ( the `3332` port should be allowed through the firewall )
- Open the browser and type `192.169.1.150:3332` , type the `password` and the `username`
- Drag an drop your files ( bidirectional) after giving the `username` and the `password` generated by the android application.

Comment: Even though that wasn't the question it works for what I want. If nobody has a solution as to how to mount a Moto G then I will give you the point :). Thanks!.

Comment: @Mariel Please upgrade `libmtp` from backports then try to mount your device following the steps describrd on your question https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie-backports/libmtp